# Error(Mac OS): sudo pip install MySQl-python

Tags: mysql, django, xcode, macos, cc

I have problem on command

```
sudo pip install MySQl-python
```

All log:

```
  Downloading/unpacking MySQl-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQl-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQl-python

Installing collected packages: MySQl-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQl-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Wno-null-conversion -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQl-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1ySuuV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
...
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Wno-null-conversion -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQl-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1ySuuV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQl-python
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Detonavomek/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I already download Mysql, Xcode and Command Line Tools. I have another problem with brew(brew link), and I thing that it is linked with this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [mysql-python on mac os 10.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392156/mysql-python-on-mac-os-10-9-1)

Fixed it by running:

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

before `pip install...```

Props to Romeo Mihalcea for answering his own question.