# mysql-python on mac os 10.9.1

Tags: compiler-construction, pip, mysql-python, easy-install

I can't seem to be able to install mysql-python on 10.9.1. I suspect it has something to do with latest command line tools update but I'm no expert:

```
Running MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s7/j138zlt172nf6qqpn98rhzhm0000gn/T/easy_install-kq86vo/MySQL-python-1.2.5/egg-dist-tmp-edndmM
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Same error with pip as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by running:

`export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments`

before `pip install...```

Comment: I got no idea. I can't remember where I found it but it looks like setting the ENV for the compiler to not complain too much on unused arguments.

Answer (score 6):

I just like to improve your answer, which helped me, too:

On MacShell do the following:

```
sudo su
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
pip install MySQL-python
```

Otherwise these Options won't be used.

Cheers!

Comment: No idea why, but the accepted answer wasn't working for me. This one worked right off the bat, so I'm guessing the exports weren't working for the sudo user?

Comment: @Hal That's true. The exports were made in usercontext. They are not valid in rootcontext. So you have to do them after you switch to root.