# install Fabric on virtualenv on mac os x Maverick

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I try to install on Fabric on virtualenv on mac os x Maverick with command `pip install fabric`

I got an error when my mac builds pycrypto:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

- Xcode version: Xcode 5.1 (5B130a)
- Command line tools: Xcode 5.1 (commandline_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__march_2014.dmg)
- python 2.7.6
- pip 1.5.4

complete log: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NvzGcN0a

`pip install fabric` on my system works, but when I activate my virtualenv and try to install Fabric on it, it does not.

Any idea where my problem is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [mysql-python on mac os 10.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392156/mysql-python-on-mac-os-10-9-1)

Fixed it by running:

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

before `pip install...```

Props to Romeo Mihalcea for answering his own question.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I don't want to know how you found the solution :)